# Which modules of mootools more I am using?

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-more

All mootools more modules are included in my app, but I would like to remove the ones I am not using. Is there a quick way to know which modules I am using starting from the script depending on mootools more?

Comment: If you post the JS you have maybe we can help figure out which modules you are using.

Comment: I can do it manually, I was just wondering if there were something helping to automate the process, like online tools or similar. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no easy way, I am afraid. you can spy on stuff while your app runs so you can get some usage/coverage stats but because mootools is prototypal, the extensions to Array/String/Function/Date etc that more does may be more complicated to catch.

To catch classes that have been instantiated, build a list and use something like that:

```
Object.monitor = function(obj, match){
    var keys = (function(obj){
            // include from prototype also, any function.
            var keys = [], key;
            for (key in obj) typeof obj[key] === 'function' && keys.push(key);
            return keys;
        }(obj)),
        log = function(what, method){
            // more use goes red in console.
            console.log(obj, method, what);
        },
        counters = {};

    keys.forEach(function(key){
        var orig = obj[key];
        Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
            get: function(){
                key in counters || (counters[key] = 0);
                counters[key]++;
                key.test(match) && log(counters[key], key);
                return orig;
            }
        });
    });
};


var protos = [Fx.Reveal, Fx.Slide, Request.JSONP]; // etc etc - stuff you are unsure of.
protos.forEach(function(klass){
    Object.monitor(klass.prototype, /\$constructor/);
});

new Request.JSONP({});
```

as soon as any of these items gets instantiated OR extended, the constructor will get referenced and you will get the log to show it. http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/8nCe6/ - this will instantiate `Request.JSONP()`.

I wrote the `Object.monitor` to spy on methods being called on a particular instance but the same principle applies. The console formatting only works nice in FireBug and WebInspector - native FF console needs to be made simple.

http://fragged.org/spy-on-any-method-on-an-object-and-profile-number-of-times-called_1661.html

you can use it to spy on say, `Array.prototype` or any suchlike as well - but the difficulty is the code complexity of more. Hard to really nail it down :(

probably easier to concatenate all your scripts EXCEPT for mootools-more then grep for known classes / methods from the Types.

Answer (score 1):

Did you compress the file?

If you haven't removed the original comments from your build, there should be a link at the top of your file with a list of the included packages and a link. e.g.

```
// Load this file's selection again by visiting: http://mootools.net/more/065f2f092ece4e3b32bb5214464cf926
```

If you don't have the link, but other comments are included, search the file for `script:` and you should get a list back of all the included packages.